# NSDictionary Not Getting First Item JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Maybe somebody can help. I am trying to get the location name for the google maps location and latitude in the URL below. As you can see from the JSON that it is first opening the results then the address_components. I am trying to get the first long_name and short_name in the JSON but instead the code I have below is only giving me the last long_name and short_name in the JSON.

Maybe someone has some type of idea, I have tried everything at this stage and nothing seems to solve the issue.

Thanks,

CurtisB

```
 -(void)getPlaceName
    {
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",53.348623,-6.243089];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        //Next we need a NSURLSession instance
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

        //All tasks (there are three, see documentation) are created from an NSURLSession instance
        //We want a DataTask
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            //This "block" (of code) will be executed when the call is complete

            //Serialize the JSON to Foundation objects
            NSDictionary *geocodeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            //Parse through the JSON to get to where we want, address_components array
            NSArray *resultsArray = geocodeDictionary[@"results"];
            NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = resultsArray[1];
            NSArray *addressComponents = resultsDictionary[@"address_components"];



            //Declare variables to hold desired results
            NSString *longName;
            NSString *shortName;

            //The address_components array contains many dictionaries,
            //we loop through each dictionary and check the types array
            for (NSDictionary *addressComponentDictionary in addressComponents) {

                    longName = addressComponentDictionary[@"long_name"];
                    shortName = addressComponentDictionary[@"short_name"];

            }

            //Test log to see we are correct
            NSLog(@"Long name for GetAddress is: %@", longName);
            NSLog(@"Short Name is: %@", shortName);
        }];

        [dataTask resume];
    }
```

JSON LOG:

```
[8948:3198407] {
    results =     (
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = "National College of Ireland";
                    "short_name" = "National College of Ireland";
                    types =                     (
                        premise
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Mayor Street Lower";
                    "short_name" = "Mayor Street Lower";
                    types =                     (
                        route
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "International Financial Services Centre";
                    "short_name" = "International Financial Services Centre";
                    types =                     (
                        "sublocality_level_1",
                        sublocality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        locality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin 1";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin 1";
                    types =                     (
                        "postal_town"
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin City";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin City";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "National College of Ireland, Mayor Street Lower, International Financial Services Centre, Dublin 1, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.34914449999999";
                        lng = "-6.2420244";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.3484171";
                        lng = "-6.2435218";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.3487808";
                    lng = "-6.242773100000001";
                };
                "location_type" = ROOFTOP;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.3501297802915";
                        lng = "-6.241424119708499";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.3474318197085";
                        lng = "-6.244122080291502";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = "ChIJ7fLaG40OZ0gRJsCRPZA1_iA";
            types =             (
                premise
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Excise Walk";
                    "short_name" = "Excise Walk";
                    types =                     (
                        route
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        locality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin City";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin City";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "Excise Walk, Dublin, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.3492304";
                        lng = "-6.2434942";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.3484317";
                        lng = "-6.243662899999999";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.34883110000001";
                    lng = "-6.243578599999999";
                };
                "location_type" = "GEOMETRIC_CENTER";
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.3501800302915";
                        lng = "-6.242229569708497";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.3474820697085";
                        lng = "-6.244927530291502";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = "ChIJG_rIHI0OZ0gRHTz7pFf9r7o";
            types =             (
                route
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = "North Dock";
                    "short_name" = "North Dock";
                    types =                     (
                        neighborhood,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        locality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin City";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin City";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "North Dock, Dublin, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.3608191";
                        lng = "-6.1894282";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.34522";
                        lng = "-6.2549399";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.3497493";
                    lng = "-6.2306567";
                };
                "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.3608191";
                        lng = "-6.1894282";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.34522";
                        lng = "-6.2549399";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = "ChIJr9h9M_oOZ0gRrycKzPZj46A";
            types =             (
                neighborhood,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin Northside";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin Northside";
                    types =                     (
                        neighborhood,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ashtown;
                    "short_name" = Ashtown;
                    types =                     (
                        "sublocality_level_1",
                        sublocality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        locality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin City";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin City";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "Dublin Northside, Ashtown, Dublin, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.4088667";
                        lng = "-6.0358715";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.34558130000001";
                        lng = "-6.381769299999999";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.3815507";
                    lng = "-6.1922052";
                };
                "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.4088667";
                        lng = "-6.0358715";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.34558130000001";
                        lng = "-6.381769299999999";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = ChIJvUSkJbcPZ0gRyXXPH9MSQwk;
            types =             (
                neighborhood,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        locality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin City";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin City";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "Dublin, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.42521010000001";
                        lng = "-6.0439235";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.22343009999999";
                        lng = "-6.4474846";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.3498053";
                    lng = "-6.2603097";
                };
                "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.42521010000001";
                        lng = "-6.0439235";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.22343009999999";
                        lng = "-6.4474846";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = ChIJL6wn6oAOZ0gRoHExl6nHAAo;
            types =             (
                locality,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Dublin City";
                    "short_name" = "Dublin City";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "Dublin City, Co. Dublin, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.4111566";
                        lng = "-6.1131916";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.2988569";
                        lng = "-6.3870807";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.3603142";
                    lng = "-6.315054200000001";
                };
                "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.4111566";
                        lng = "-6.1131916";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.2988569";
                        lng = "-6.3870807";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = ChIJv2RI7foRZ0gRwAKA8azHAAM;
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = Dublin;
                    "short_name" = Dublin;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "Co. Dublin, Ireland";
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.6347257";
                        lng = "-5.9962748";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.1781971";
                        lng = "-6.5468798";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.3824769";
                    lng = "-6.3133674";
                };
                "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "53.6347257";

                        lng = "-5.9962748";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "53.1781971";
                        lng = "-6.5468798";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = ChIJv2RI7foRZ0gRwAKA8azHABg;
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = Ireland;
                    "short_name" = IE;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = Ireland;
            geometry =             {
                bounds =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "55.4351345";
                        lng = "-5.994700099999999";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "51.4199312";
                        lng = "-10.66958";
                    };
                };
                location =                 {
                    lat = "53.41291";
                    lng = "-8.24389";
                };
                "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "55.4351345";
                        lng = "-5.99471";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "51.4199312";
                        lng = "-10.6694501";
                    };
                };
            };
            "place_id" = "ChIJ-ydAXOS6WUgRCPTbzjQSfM8";
            types =             (
                country,
                political
            );
        }
    );
    status = OK; }
```

Comment: can you log the `geocodeDictionary` to see what you get

Comment: You are looping: ` for (NSDictionary *addressComponentDictionary in addressComponents)` That's why you get the last value. If you don't understand why, put logs INSIDE the loop, printing `addressComponents`, the values of `longName` and `shortName` also before and after doing `longName = addressComponentDictionary[@"long_name"];`. @sken3r.MI: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.348623,-6.243089&sensor=false

Comment: Just added the JSON log there. Thank you Larme, I will try that and see how I get on. Do you recommend removing the loop??

Comment: Just a little remark: first object is index 0(zero)

Comment: if you need only 1st name then just use
       ` NSString *short_name = [addr valueForKey:@"short_name"];NSString *long_name = [addr valueForKey:@"long_name"]objectatindex [0]];
        NSString *short_name = [addr valueForKey:@"short_name"]objectatindex [0]];`

Comment: addr is your addresscomponent array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is going over all of the `address_components` and assigning their values to your `longName` and `shortName` variables, thus when the loop finishes only the last retrieved values in the array will be stored.  If you only want the first set then you probably want to do something like this:

```
if ( addressComponents.count > 0 ) {
    NSDictionary *componentDict = addressComponents[0];
    longName = componentDict[@"long_name"];
    shortName = componentDict[@"short_name"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//The address_components array contains many dictionaries,
        //we loop through each dictionary and check the types array
        for (NSDictionary *addressComponentDictionary in addressComponents) {

                longName = addressComponentDictionary[@"long_name"];
                shortName = addressComponentDictionary[@"short_name"];

        }
```

as Larme said your problem is here, instead of `longName` and `shortName`.
Create 2 arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *longNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
NSMutableArray *shortNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
for (NSDictionary *addressComponentDictionary in addressComponents) {
    [longNameArray addObject:addressComponentDictionary[@"long_name"]];
    [shortNameArray addObject:addressComponentDictionary[@"short_name"]];
  }
```

This will give you the full list of elements found in the request.

**Update - Get only the first element**

If you need only the first element, get the first item from array

```
//This check will ensure that the array is not empty
if (addressComponents.count > 0) {
    NSDictionary *addressComponentDictionary = addressComponents[0];
    longName = addressComponentDictionary[@"long_name"];
    shortName = addressComponentDictionary[@"short_name"];
}
```